# I need to add an image on the page so that it's covering part of a form

Tags: html, css, forms, image

I'm trying to place an image over a form, like displayed in this image:
[example of the effect i'm trying to achieve.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dflbF.jpg)

The image I'm trying to use is this one: [Ribbon photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dGkgC.png)

Here is the code for the form:

```css
#contactform1{text-align:center;margin-bottom:40px;color:#1a1a1a;}
#contactform1 .sendmessagetext{padding-top:50px;text-transform:none;padding-bottom:35px;}
#contactform1 form{width:75%; margin:0 auto;}
```

```html
<section id="contactform1" class="cform">
   <div class="wrap">
    <h2 class="sendmessagetext">Get in Touch</h2>
<form name="simp_cont" method="post" action="<?=$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];?>#cform1" class="contact" onSubmit="return validateForm(this)">
 <input class="input" name="captcha" style="position:absolute; left:-9999px;" id="captcha" type="text" />
 <input type="text" name="fname" id="name" placeholder="NAME">
 <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" placeholder="PHONE NUMBER">
 <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="EMAIL ADDRESS">
 <input type="text" name="footage" id="footage" placeholder="ESTIMATED SQUARE FOOTAGE">
 <textarea class="textarea" name="message" placeholder="COMMENTS"></textarea>
 <input name="form_name" type="hidden" value="contact_form" />
 <button type="submit" id="sliderbutton2" name='submit'>SEND MESSAGE</button>
</form>
<br><br>
   <div class="clear"></div>
 </div>
</section>
```

Any tips on how to achieve this effect would be greatly appreciated! Google led me to a lot of answers to questions SIMILAR to mine in text, but not achieving the same effect. I'm not just trying to place an image above the form, I want it to be on a layer above it, like displayed in the image.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this it worked for me (style)

```
    body { margin : 0;background: black; }
    #contactform1{text-align:center;margin:40px auto;color:#1a1a1a;background: #f1f1f1;width : 700px;}
    #contactform1 .sendmessagetext{padding-top:50px;text-transform:none;padding-bottom:35px;}
    #contactform1 form{width:75%; margin:0 auto;}
    #name,#phone,#email,#footage,.textarea { margin : 10px auto;height : 30px;width : 450px ; }
    .textarea { resize : none; height : 100px; }
    img { position:absolute;margin: -30% auto auto 60%;z-index:10; }
```

Body part is

```
 <body >

<section id="contactform1" class="cform">
        <div class="wrap">
            <h2 class="sendmessagetext">Get in Touch</h2>
  <form name="simp_cont" method="post" action="<?=$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];?>#cform1" class="contact" onSubmit="return validateForm(this)">
<input class="input" name="captcha" style="position:absolute; left:-9999px;" id="captcha" type="text" />
<input type="text" name="fname" id="name" placeholder="NAME"><br />
<input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" placeholder="PHONE NUMBER"><br />
<input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="EMAIL ADDRESS"><br />
<input type="text" name="footage" id="footage" placeholder="ESTIMATED SQUARE FOOTAGE">
<textarea class="textarea" name="message" placeholder="COMMENTS"></textarea><br />
<input name="form_name" type="hidden" value="contact_form" /><br />
<button type="submit" id="sliderbutton2" name='submit'>SEND MESSAGE</button>
</form>
<br><br>
        <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
</section>
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/dGkgC.png" />

</body>
```

Well,you can add some bootstrapping to make it more responsive.

Answer (score 0):

1. Add new element `<div class="ribbon"></div>` inside form
2. Add to form `position: relative`
3. Add `#contactform1 form .ribbon` style in css (see below)
4. Change `top: 0; right: 0;` properties of `.ribbon` to correctly position the element

```css
#contactform1{text-align:center;margin-bottom:40px;color:#1a1a1a;}
#contactform1 .sendmessagetext{padding-top:50px;text-transform:none;padding-bottom:35px;}
#contactform1 form {width:75%; margin:0 auto; position: relative;}
#contactform1 form .ribbon {
  background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/dGkgC.png) 0 0 no-repeat transparent;
  width: 213px;
  height: 303px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<section id="contactform1" class="cform">
  <div class="wrap">
    <h2 class="sendmessagetext">
      Get in Touch
    </h2>
    <form name="simp_cont" method="post" action=" <?=$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];?> #cform1" class="contact" onSubmit="return validateForm(this)">
      <div class="ribbon"></div>
      <input class="input" name="captcha" style="position:absolute; left:-9999px;" id="captcha" type="text"/>
      <input type="text" name="fname" id="name" placeholder="NAME"/>
      <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" placeholder="PHONE NUMBER"/>
      <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="EMAIL ADDRESS"/>
      <input type="text" name="footage" id="footage" placeholder="ESTIMATED SQUARE FOOTAGE"/>
      <textarea class="textarea" name="message" placeholder="COMMENTS"></textarea>
      <input name="form_name" type="hidden" value="contact_form"/>
      <button type="submit" id="sliderbutton2" name='submit'>
        SEND MESSAGE
      </button>
    </form>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <div class="clear"></div>
  </div>
</section>
```